# clear and undo clear the array

Tags: javascript

If I do have the following code then empty the arry:

```
var a1 = [1,2,3];
a1 = [];
//returns []
```

But I'm trying to make  a function to clear and undo clear the array, it's not working as expected:

```
var foo = ['f','o','o'];
var storeArray;
function clearArray(a){
   storeArray = a;
   a = [];
}
function undoClearArray(a){
   a = storeArray;
}

clearArray(foo);
foo; //still returns ['f','o','o'] 

//but expected result is: []
```

Comment: That's not emptying an array. That's pointing to a new, empty array.

Comment: That clears the local array 'a' thats sent to function but not actual array. You can do it like below,
function clearArray(a){
   storeArray = a;   
}
function undoClearArray(a){
   a = storeArray;
}

Answer (score 3):

Here's the problem:

You assign an array to a variable `foo.`

Then you pass this object to your function which stores it in another variable `a`. Now you have one object that two variable are pointing at. In the function you then reassign `a` to a different object an empty array `[]`. Now `a` points at the empty object and `foo` still points at the original object. You didn't change foo by reassigning `a`.

Here's a concise way to store you're array:

```
var storeArray = [];
function clearArray(a){
    while (a.length>0){ 
        storeArray.push(a.shift()) //now a is empty and storeArray has a copy
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried something different. Maybe it's dirty, but the storage itself is on the object.

the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/44EF5/3/)

```
//define the object to hold the old data
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "storage", {
    enumerable: false,
    configureable: true,
    get: function () {
        return bValue;
    },
    set: function (newValue) {
        bValue = newValue;
    }
});

//define the prototype function clear to clear the data
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "clear", {
    enumerable: false,
    writable: false,
    value: function () {
        this.storage = this.slice(0);         //copy the data to the storage
        for (var p in this) {
           if (this.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
                delete this[p];               //delete the data
           }
        }
        return this;  //return the object if you want assign the return value
    }
});

//define the prototype function restore to reload the data
Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "restore", {
    enumerable: false,
    writable: false,
    value: function () {
       var a = this.storage.slice(0);       //copy the storage to a local var
        for (var p in this.storage) {
            if (this.storage.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
                this[p] = a[p];              //assign the pointer to the new variable
                delete this.storage[p];      //delete the storage            
            }
        }
        return this;
    }
});

var a = ['f','o','o'];
console.log(a); //--> displays ['f','o','o']

a.clear();
console.log(a); //--> displays []

a.restore();
console.log(a); //--> displays ['f','o','o']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function clearArray(a){
   storeArray = a.slice(0);
   return a.length = 0;
}
```

or set `foo.length = 0;`

Comment: When you set a.length = 0, this has the side effect of setting storeArray length to zero since they are the same object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `splice()` method to delete all elements of an array likes below

```
function clearArray(a){
   storeArray = a;
   a.splice(0,a.length);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var a = [1,2,3,4];
var tempArr ;

clearArray = function() {
    tempArr = a.slice(0);
    a.length = 0;
}

undoArray = function() {
    a = tempArr.slice(0);
}
```

Here is a small jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/66s2N/

Comment: you are working on the variable a in another context, than the questioner.

Answer (score 0):

Here's working way of what you want to achieve:

```
var foo = ['f','o','o'];
var storeArray;
function clearArray(a){
   storeArray = a.slice(0);
   for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++)
      delete a[i];

   a.length = 0;
}
function undoClearArray(a){
   for (var i=0; i<storeArray.length; i++)
       a.push(storeArray[i]);
}

console.log(foo);

clearArray(foo);
console.log(foo); //now foo is []

undoClearArray(foo);
console.log(foo); // now foo is ['f','o','o']
```

http://jsfiddle.net/44EF5/1/

When you do:

`var a1 = [1,2,3];
a1 = [];`

it's as if you've written:

`var a1 = [1,2,3];
var a1 = [];`

You're overwriting variables.

Now, why your approach doesn't work - in JS there's no passing by reference. MarkM response explains what's happening within the function.

Now, why does the above work - while you've got two variables pointing towards the same array, nothing prevents you from modifying that array. As such `storeArray = a.slice(0)` will create a copy of the array. Then by using `delete` we're removing all values of the array, and then as `length` isn't enumerable (so using `for (var i in a)` wouldn't help) we reassign the length of the array. This has removed the values of original array, while creating a new array assigned to `storeArray`.

Answer (score 0):

Just update your both function with below ones

```
function clearArray(a){
   storeArray = a.slice(0);
   a.length = 0;
}
function undoClearArray(a){
  a = storeArray;
  return a;
}
```

in `undoClearAray()` we are returning the variable which have new reference(in your clearArray(), Both the original and new array refer to the same object. If a referenced object changes, the changes are visible to both the new and original arrays). so use it as `foo=undoClearArray(foo);` for old values.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var foo = ['f','o','o'];
var storeArray;
function clearArray(a){
   storeArray = a;
   a = [];
   return a;
}
function undoClearArray(a){
   a = storeArray;
}

foo = clearArray(foo);
foo; //returns []
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use wrappers to do this quite nicely. First create a wrapper function with the additional methods defined, then create your array using that function instead of `[]`. Here is an example (see [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/neelsg/5E5s5/)):

```
var extendedArray = function() {
    var arr = [];
    arr.push.apply(arr, arguments);

    arr.clearArray = function() {
        this.oldValue = this.slice(0);
        this.length = 0;
    }

    arr.undoArray = function() {
        this.length = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < this.oldValue.length; i++) {
            this.push(this.oldValue[i]);
        }
    }
    return arr;
};

var a = extendedArray('f', 'o', 'o');

alert(a);
a.clearArray();
alert(a);
a.undoArray();
alert(a);
```